# Unable to spread an object in Node v8.3.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am attempting use the spread on an object in node v8.3.0 and it is not working. Switched up to the latest LTS version (v8.9.1) and no luck still. I understand that the spread assignment only works on arrays or iterables since node v6 but apparently v8.3.0 came with object spread. Can anyone confirm this, and if yes, is it working for you?

For example,

```
const data = {
    custom_data1: "NodeJS",
    custom_data2: "Spring",
    custom_data3: "Kitura"
}

console.log(...data) // this returns 'undefined is not a function'.
```

UPDATE: I screwed up by mentioning destructuring in my earlier posting. I meant to say spread. Thanks for those who corrected me! Appreciate it.

Comment: Object destructuring? This is spread syntax.

Comment: in order to destructure the syntax is `const {custom_data1} = data`

Comment: It does the same thing in Chrome, it's not a problem with node, it's a problem with your syntax and what you want to do, as @Li357 mentionned, this is spread syntax.

Comment: @KonradD I am expecting the object to be logged into the console. It's just an example though, the actual code is me trying to destructure an object into another object. Something like this:

`const data1 = { name: 'Aravind', id: '92' }

let newData = {
   ...data1,
   country: 'Malaysia',
   bloodType: 'O-'
}`

Comment: @user3056928 Then you should have said that. That's nothing like the code in your question.

Comment: Oh dear, I screwed up. I meant spread, not destructure! Correcting the post now.

Comment: `const data1 = { name: 'Aravind', id: '92' }; let newData = { ...data1, country: 'Malaysia', bloodType: 'O-' }` is working fine for me in Node 8.9.1 (current LTS version).

Comment: @JLRishe I just moved it to a new declaration and now everything works!

Answer (score 4):

Put curly braces on the target. It should be:

```js
var data = {
    custom_data1: "NodeJS",
    custom_data2: "Spring",
    custom_data3: "Kitura",
};

console.log({ ...data });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data1 = {
    custom_data1: "NodeJS",
    custom_data2: "Spring",
    custom_data3: "Kitura"
}

var data2 = {
    new_key: "Spring",
    custom_data3: "Overwrite"
}

console.log({...data, ...data2})
```

Try this one